# Not able to Start, stop, restart mongoDB as service

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

Here is my mongodb config file (Amazon - EC2 User)

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.


replication:
  replSetName: devRepl
```

i am getting error when running mongoDB as **`>sudo service mongod restart`**

```
Stopping mongod:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting mongod:                                           [FAILED]
```

but working perfectly if running using config file **`>sudo mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`**
where i am wrong ?

Comment: check your logs and paste some info

Comment: Here you can download an nice start, stop, restart script: https://github.com/patrick0585/Mongo_Start_Stop